# Stylesheet control of system panel font colors?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, style, stylesheet, text

I'm trying to make a custom dark mode stylesheet, and I started with Kuba's great [DarkPackage](https://github.com/kubaPod/DevTools/blob/master/DevTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/DevTools/ReverseColorPackage.nb#L41).

The issue is **how to deal with text in panels** (you can barely see the white-on-white text, unless you select the element with your mouse):

[image]

***My question:*** *how to control the color of text in paneled boxes from a stylesheet definition cell*?

The most common examples of this are:

1. White text in values of `InformationPanel[title, {key->value, ...}]` from GeneralUtilities` (e.g. the panel used in Classify, NetTrain, Information, etc.):

[image]

2. White text in headers of datasets:

[image]

3. Linguistic assistant text:

[image]

These are just a few cases of this need to invert the white colors on white paneled or interactive backgrounds, but at least addressing these two would solve most of the problem.

**What I've tried:**

One really bad way to solve this is to set:

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0.7, 1]]
```

Which will fix the unreadable panels, but will affect all `Text` :(

[image]

Comment: You need to have some box style that you can edit. Something like a class or tag in the CSS world, basically. That means you need to look into how `Information` makes its boxes and mess with that.

Answer (score 3):

Editing the `"DialogStyle"` cell style works for the `Information` case. In general you need to look at where the `BoxObject` of interest will inherit its styles from. In this case I just did `ToBoxes[Information[a]]` and figured it out like that.

```
StyleSheetEdit[
 "DialogStyle",
 FontColor -> Red,
 "MakeCell" -> True
 ]
```

```
Information[a]
```

[image]

Comment: What about text in the linguistic assistant?

Comment: The raw text doesn't have it bound, but the `NamespaceBox` inherits styles it seems. Styling `"LinguisticAssistant"` works. I'd be careful about messing with that one, though. The Wolfram Alpha people hard coded a lot of shit.

Comment: Ah and "NaturalLanguageInput"

Comment: Where is `"NaturalLanguageInput"` used?

Comment: I found it by text searching in `default/core/..`

Comment: @M.R. what styles does it affect?

Comment: The equals and double-equals cells: "WolframAlphaLong/Short"

Comment: Hmm it didn’t change anything for me. But for those you can just use the cell style names, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104542/discussion-between-m-r-and-b3m2a1).