# How to modify default options of Dataset

Tags: output-formatting, color, dataset, customization, stylesheet

I try to make a dark stylesheet based on the `ReverseColor` theme. However, dataset headers are barely readable.

[image]

This question is related to others such as
[Question 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214788/stylesheet-control-of-system-panel-font-colors)
and
[Question 2](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1699643).
But no solution has been found yet.

It seems that the new options for `Dataset` called `HeaderStyle`/`HeaderBackground` introduced in Version 12.1 might help, since it is now possible to modify headers:

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3|>,<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 4|>}, HeaderStyle -> White, HeaderBackground -> Black]
```

However, any small change in the dataset restores the default settings:

```
ds[All, ;; 2]
```

I tried to modify the default values of HeaderStyle (None) and HeaderBackground (Automatic) by typing:

```
SetOptions[Dataset,HeaderBackground->Black,HeaderStyle->White]
```

Typing `Options[Dataset]` indicates that it changes the default values of these options but
does not seem to apply since, for example, headers of:

```
Dataset[{<|"a"->3,"b"->4|>}]
```

and:

```
ds[All,;;2]
```

have the default format.

Any idea to modify the default layout of dataset headers from a stylesheet or at least for an entire notebook?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SetOptions[Dataset, HeaderBackground -> Black, HeaderStyle -> White, 
  ItemStyle -> Red];

ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 4|>}]
```

[image]

```
ds[1]
```

[image]

A cumbersome way to inject the options is to wrap dataset objects with `Dataset[#, Options[Dataset]]&`:

```
{Dataset[#,Options[Dataset]]& @ ds, Dataset[#,Options[Dataset]]& @ ds[1]}
```

[image]

A more convenient work-around is to use[`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) to inject the options into objects with head `Dataset`:

```
$PrePrint = If[Head[#] === Dataset, Dataset[#, Options[Dataset]], #] &;

ds
```

[image]

```
ds[1]
```

[image]

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The $Preprint solution is exactly what I missed to modify the formatting of my current Notebook. Many thanks @kglr ! The first solution seems a bit less useful since typing for example `ds[2]` removes the formatting.

But can this $PrePrint solution be introduced in the stylesheet definition, with something like `Cell[StyleData["Dataset"], ...]` ?

Comment: @Vly, I don't know if/how it can be done via stylesheets. An easy way to avoid setting `$PrePrint` in every mma session is to add `$PrePrint =...` to the `init.m` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kglr! Of course, the best would have been to be able to include it in the stylesheet definition. But adding `$PrePrint=...` line to the init.m file perfectly extends the bevahior to all the notebooks. Also, now, I know the use of this init.m file. Thank you again!

Comment: @Vly, my pleasure.Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.

Comment: @kglr    My question is not above code, but about adjusting number of rows in Dataset.  In the above table it is seen "rows 1-20 of 1309"  In general,using Dataset,  How can we adjust the number of rows that we can see in the table?  For instance, can we make it "1-40" instead of "1-20" . Moreover, using Data set,  How can we see all list in one single table?

Comment: @gunes, see [the answers in this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97534/125)